# Why do I get the "rmdir ... Permission denied:" error when trying to delete an (empty) dir with PHP CLI in Windows 10?

Tags: php, windows-10, command-line-interface, file-permissions, rmdir

***Code:***

```
rmdir('C:\Users\ABC\Pictures\Camera Roll');
```

***Result:***

> rmdir(C:\Users\ABC\Pictures\Camera Roll): Permission denied:

***Analysis:***

The dir is not deleted, and that error is logged.

***Information:***

The dir is empty. The dir was not created by me but by Windows 10. (The whole point of this is to constantly delete it if found, so I don't have to manually delete it all the time as Windows keeps recreating it.)

I don't have any special permissions, users, or exotic/strange configuration of my system in any way. My PHP CLI scripts typically seem to be able to do anything I tell them to, but they won't delete that dir for some reason.

Comment: Try this, it might help ~ https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php#95703. There's a few other comments in there relating to Windows permissions so give them all a read

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Does it work with other folders, maybe some without that space in between?